# Angular cli ng build failing as component @angular/core not found

Tags: angular, angular-cli

```
### Versions.
@angular/cli: 1.0.1
node: 6.9.5
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.1.0
@angular/compiler: 4.1.0
@angular/core: 4.1.0
@angular/forms: 4.1.0
@angular/http: 4.1.0
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.0
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.0
@angular/router: 4.1.0
@angular/cli: 1.0.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.0
```

#### Repro steps.

created new ng app
1)  ng new angtest -sd \src\main\app
2)  ng build

fails with below error log

#### The log given by the failure.

> ERROR in D:/../angtest/src/main/app/app/app.component.ts (1,27): Cann
>   ot find module '@angular/core'.
>
> ERROR in D:/../angtest/src/main/app/app/app.component.ts (8,14): Expe
>   rimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change
>   in a futu re release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to
>   remove this warning.
>
> ERROR in D:/../angtest/src/main/app/app/app.module.ts (1,31): Cannot
>   find module '@angular/platform-browser'.
>
> ERROR in D:/../angtest/src/main/app/app/app.module.ts (2,26): Cannot
>   find module '@angular/core'.
>
> ERROR in D:/../angtest/src/main/app/app/app.module.ts (3,29): Cannot
>   find module '@angular/forms'.
>
> ERROR in D:/../angtest/src/main/app/app/app.module.ts (4,28): Cannot
>   find module '@angular/http'.
>
> ERROR in D:/../angtest/src/main/app/app/app.module.ts (20,14): Experi
>   mental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change
>   in a future  release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to
>   remove this warning.
>
> ERROR in D:/../angtest/src/main/app/main.ts (1,32): Cannot find modul
>   e '@angular/core'.

angular-cli.json file as below

```
    {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "uds3"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src\\main\\app",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "\\src\\main\\app/tsconfig.app.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "\\src\\main\\app/tsconfig.spec.json"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you install the npm modules: `npm i` ?

Comment: Yes i did npm i after that i have faced above issue

Comment: is `node_modules` called like this and peer to the `src` folder? also, not sure if it has anything to do with the "\\" separator for folders in your config - try switching to "/"; also: try removing node_modules and re-installing see if it works with success - if you are behind a proxy some configs are needed... dunno what else could be the issue

Comment: Thanks for your time and it was my silly mistake . I am able to fix the issue , it is due the forward slash in the command.changed to backward slash and was able to resolve.               1) ng new angtest -sd "src/main/app"